# Apollo query loading is always false

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am new to Apollo. I'm trying to create loading spinner. I am using `class components` and I can't use hooks. The only way to fetch data for `class components` is through `client.query()` The problem is that loading state is always false.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/express',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: 'true',
    },
  },
})
```

```
export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return client
    .query({
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      query: PRODUCT_QUERY,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.loading + '<-- spinner')
      return result
    })
}
```

[image: console.log]

@apollo/client: "^3.5.6"
react: "^17.0.2"

Answer (score 2):

You are using an apollo Query- which returns a promise with `.then()`, which implies that

```
(result) => {
      console.log(result.loading + '<-- spinner')
      return result
    })
```

will only be called **After** your query has been solved, which will never show loading to be true. If you really want to monitor the state of the query , I would probably do something like this:

```
const { data , loading , error }=client.query({
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      query: PRODUCT_QUERY,
    })
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but I would have to pass client as prop to my component container (smart-component)
Is there a way to do this without passing apollo client to my component?

Comment: @Pavels actually yes there is a way: use the `useQuery` hook provided by apollo.           `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(yourQuery)`